# Woocommerce how to remove function in includes file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove (or comment out) 3 lines of code within one of Woocommerce's include files.

However, I don't want to directly modify the original source code, but have a fix that is potentially in the functions.php file of my child theme.

The Woocommerce include file that contains the code I need to remove is includes/class-wc-session-handler.php

The function I need to modify is...

```
public function generate_customer_id() {
    $customer_id = '';

    //if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        //$customer_id = strval( get_current_user_id() );
    //}

    if ( empty( $customer_id ) ) {
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php';
        $hasher      = new PasswordHash( 8, false );
        $customer_id = md5( $hasher->get_random_bytes( 32 ) );
    }

    return $customer_id;
}
```

As you see the comment tags // have commented out the snipped of code I don't want to execute.

How can I build a solution that could be in the functions.php file?

Comment: You can do one thing, just copy plugin file in child theme with exact location as plugin folder and then just removed those line of code that's the easy and time saver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can not post the comments yet, so answering it here.

You can try to delete the lines of this function in the file in Child-Theme Folder instead of commenting them out. If this function is still running there will two other possible reasons.
One - You need to clear the cache.
Two - This function is running from somewhere else.